# Why it seems not necessary to include some STL headers

Tags: c++, stl

I think some headers need to be included to compile with gcc(4.9),

```
#include <algorithm> // for std::transform
#include <numeric>   // for std::adjacent_difference
```

However, I found it's not necessary include them at all, I can still call
for example, the following functions

```
std::adjacent_difference (V1.begin(), V1.end(), V2.begin());
std::transform(V2.begin(), V2.end(), V3.begin(), V4.begin(), std::divides<double>());
```

Maybe I have misunderstood the mechanism of including header files...Any hint?

Comment: Then you are just lucky that you include some *other* header file which includes the needed header files.

Comment: If you use it, include it.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg is correct. You should *always* include the header files you need. Sometimes some of the headers you include, themselves include other STL headers, and this is why you are seeing this behavior. Some of the files you're already including likely include `<algorithm>` and `<numeric>`; but this is an implementation detail. You should not rely on it :)

Comment: what are `V1` - `V4` actually? Plain arrays?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is quite typical for a header to include other headers. The headers included by header x will be included in any file that includes x. That should be trivial to understand once you grasp what *including* a file in another means. In this case, one of the standard headers happened to be included in another.

Files included by headers can change between versions. If you don't include a required header, your program may break under another (version of) standard library even though it may appear to work in the current implementation. Of course, this applies to other libraries as well.

Comment: Just as a concrete example, the last few versions of g++ have been trying to remove unnecessary header includes from the standard library, to speed up compiling user's code (as all those headers have to be parsed), and I seen this breaking code which was not including sufficient headers.

Comment: if a header(A.h) includes other headers(B.h, C.h), then all the content will be visible in .cpp files that include A.h, correct? It's really strange, I can use std::vector<double> without specifying include<vector>...

Comment: @lorniper yes, you are correct. It's not really strange, it just means that one of the included headers currently does include `<vector>`.

Answer (score 3):

The C++ standard says the following in section 17.6.5.2 [res.on.headers]:

> A C++ header may include other C++ headers.

For your question, this means a compiler can just act as if you included other C++ headers. In your example, the compiler is allowed to include the `<numeric>` header if you include `<algorithm>`, or vice versa.

But that's not the whole story. The standard also says:

> A C++ header shown in its synopsis as including other C++ headers
>   shall provide the declarations and definitions that appear in the
>   synopses of those other headers.

And:

> The C standard headers [...] shall include only their corresponding
>   C++ standard header [...]

*(Note that I am quoting from the last free C++11 draft. The final version of the ISO standard is not free. See https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard.)*

The `<utility>` header is an example of a C++ header which is guaranteed to include another. Its synopsis *explitly* includes `<initializer_list>`. Which means a conforming compiler **must** accept the following:

```
#include <utility>
// #include <initializer_list> // not needed

int main()
{
    std::initializer_list<int> x = {};
}
```

For the C headers, in contrast, this means that the following **must not** compile:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "\n"; // must not compile
}
```

What the standard says is surely confirmed by your implementation's documentation. For example, the [documentation for Visual C++ 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xb3bx4w8.aspx) says:

> A C++ library header includes any other C++ library headers it needs
>   to define needed types. (Always include explicitly any C++ library
>   headers needed in a translation unit, however, lest you guess wrong
>   about its actual dependencies.) A Standard C header never includes
>   another standard header.

The advice given here is a good one; do not depend on automatic inclusion. Explicitly include everything you need.